# validacion de formulario con js

Tags: javascript

buen dia, necesito una orientación para saber que estoy haciendo mal, tengo un array

```
var detallesImei= [
  { imei1: 'aaaa', imeip: '1' },
  { imei1: 'aaaal', imeip: '1' }
];
```

quiero validar con jquery validate si el dato que voy a enviar en el formulario existe en el array, lo estoy haciendo de esta manera,

```
rules: {

  imei1:{
    existeI: function(element) {

var existeI = detallesImei.some(element1 => element1.imei1 === $( "#imei1" ).val());

return existeI;

   }

    }

    },
```

de esta manera me devuelve un booleano pero no funciona me da el siguiente error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined.  Exception occurred when checking element imei1, check the 'existeI' method.` que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: No estás creando correctamente la función, encierra _element1_ entre paréntesis: `detallesImei.some((element1) => element1.imei1 === $( "#imei1" ).val());`

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEMA**

Sucede que no estás usando correctamente el plugin [*JQuery Validation*](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). Para lograr crear la validación, debes pasar el método como argumento de la función `addMethod()` y no como elemento del objeto `rules`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Veamos una forma de implementar correctamente tu validación.

Deseas validar que el valor introducido en algún elemento tipo `input` identificado por `#imei1` no se repita en los elementos de tu lista `detallesImei`.

Entonces, lo que debes hacer es crear un método que te diga si el valor introducido en el `input` ya existe en la lista. Este método no lo vas a agregar en las reglas del validador, sino que lo vas a agregar en el objeto de métodos del validador, porque es un método personalizado.

Para ello usarás el método [`addMethod()`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) del validador de JQuery.

En este caso, te interesa validar que el campo `imei1` no contenga un valor repetido en la lista `detallesImei`.

El método [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some) del tipo `Array` devuelve un booleano, siendo `true` si una condición sobre algunos de los elementos del `Array` se cumple y `false` si ninguno de los elementos del `Array` cumple la condición.

Tu función de validación puede ser la siguiente:

```js
const imeiNotInList = function(value) {
  return !detallesImei.some(element => element.imei1 === value);
}
```

Esta función devuelve `true` sólo si el valor que pasamos como argumento es distinto de **todos** los valores almacenados en la lista. El valor pasado a nuestra función será el valor del elemento al que le asignemos la regla de validación.

Una vez que tenemos la función de validación, debemos agregarla a los mñetodos de validación, para ello hacemos lo siguiente:

```js
$.validator.addMethod(
  //nombre del método para identificar el validador
  'notInList',
  //nombre de la función a ejecutar
  imeiNotInList,
  // mensaje a mostrar si no pasa la validación
  'El imei ya existe en la lista'
);
```

Como puedes apreciar uso 3 argmuentos, el primero es el nombre con el que será conocido el método entre los métodos de mi validador, el segundo es la referencia a la función que se ejecutará al momento de validar y el tercer argumento es el mensaje que mostrará al usuario si la validación falla.

Ahora ya podemos agregar la regla personalizada a nuestro elemento para su validación, para ello establecemos las reglas de validación al elemento `form` adecuado:

```js
$('#miFormulario').validate({
  rules: {
    'imei1': {
      notInList: true
    }
  });
```

Le estamos pasando las reglas, indicando para este caso que el elemento cuyo atributo `name` es igual a `imei1` debe ser validado usando nuestra función personalizada de validación que hemos creado bajo la clave `notInList`. Cada vez que el valor del `input` sea cambiado, se ejecutará el validador. El valor del `input` es pasado a nuestra función de validación y así se obtiene el resultado esperado.

Una forma de ver este código funcionando sería la siguiente: (Uso Bootstrap para darle estilos, pero lo puedes omitir)

```js
const detallesImei= [
  { imei1: 'aaaa', imeip: '1' },
  { imei1: 'aaaal', imeip: '1' }
];

// podemos escribir la función de validacion aquí
const imeiNotInList = function(value) {
  // devolverá true si el valor no existe en la lista
  return !detallesImei.some(element => element.imei1 === value);
}

// ahora podemos añadir el método de validación
$.validator.addMethod(
  'notInList', 
  imeiNotInList,
  'El imei introducido ya existe'
);

// ahora agregamos la regla

$('#miFormulario').validate({
  rules: {
    'imei1': {
      notInList: true,
      required: true
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    console.log('Formulario válido a sido enviado')
    // para enviar el formulario, descomentar la siguiente linea
    //form.submit();
  }
});
```

```css
form .error {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha256-+BEKmIvQ6IsL8sHcvidtDrNOdZO3C9LtFPtF2H0dOHI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
      <form action="#" id="miFormulario" class="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="imei1">Introduzca un valor:</label>
          <input id="imei1" name="imei1" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <button id="validar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Enviar</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.